# calling xib inside the Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib

Can I call or integrate my existing xib files with their corresponding .h and .m to the Storyboard? I have around 6 xib files with their layout inside and i need to call them inside my new storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call your xib files in a storyboard, but you can copy and paste any views from your xib to the storyboard, and change the class of any of your storyboard view controllers to the class of the controllers that owned your xibs.